# Opencv cannot access my webcam

Tags: opencv, webcam

I have trouble with accessing webcam using opencv 2.4.3.

My System:

Hp Probook 4530s - HP Fixed HD Webcam

Ubuntu 12.10

OpenCV 2.4.3

İf I want to capture my built-in camera i get ERROR: capture is NULL

I'm using http://opencv.willowgarage.com/wiki/CameraCapture sample code.

Sample code is:

```
#include "cv.h" 
#include "highgui.h" 
#include <stdio.h>  
// A Simple Camera Capture Framework 
int main() {
CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM( CV_CAP_ANY );
if ( !capture ) {
 fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: capture is NULL \n" );
 getchar();
 return -1;
}
// Create a window in which the captured images will be presented
cvNamedWindow( "mywindow", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE );
// Show the image captured from the camera in the window and repeat
while ( 1 ) {
 // Get one frame
 IplImage* frame = cvQueryFrame( capture );
 if ( !frame ) {
   fprintf( stderr, "ERROR: frame is null...\n" );
   getchar();
   break;
 }
 cvShowImage( "mywindow", frame );
 // Do not release the frame!
 //If ESC key pressed, Key=0x10001B under OpenCV 0.9.7(linux version),
 //remove higher bits using AND operator
 if ( (cvWaitKey(10) & 255) == 27 ) break;
}
// Release the capture device housekeeping
cvReleaseCapture( &capture );
cvDestroyWindow( "mywindow" );
return 0;
}
```

I also tried with **xawtv -hwscan** using typing terminal. I get this output:

```
looking for available devices
port 129-144

type : Xvideo, image scaler
name : Intel(R) Textured Video`


/dev/video0: OK    
             [ -device /dev/video0 ]
type : libv4l

name : HP HD Webcam [Fixed]

flags:  capture
```

then I can access my webcam typing **xawtv video0**. I think I have no trouble with my webcam. 
I have trouble with opencv.

Comment: If you are using C++ give this example code a try: http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

Comment: I try your code that is in http://docs.opencv.org/modules/highgui/doc/reading_and_writing_images_and_video.html#videocapture

it doesnt work

Comment: Try using different numbers here: `VideoCapture cap(0);`, e.g., 1 and 2. If that does not help, the problem is not with OpenCV.

Comment: @Niko I know these arguments I also try 0 1 2 even -1 but this doesnt work.

Comment: try a different web cam, i.e external, as i'm sure i've read somewhere that some cameras don't work. If your able to show that another cam works, then you'll know you have a driver issue.

Comment: @Emile I know some webcamera is not supported on Linux. But My not understanding point is I can receive image from linux apps. However I cannot use with opencv. Some forums says in opencv 2.1.0 is working but I can not decide what i should.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved my problem few minutes ago. And I decided share my solution for people who handling similar error.

First I didnt install some of below packets ( I dont remember which of them, so  I paste all of them)

libjpeg62-dev

libtiff4-dev

zlib1g-dev

libjasper-dev

libavcodec-dev

libdc1394-22-dev

libgstreamer0.10-dev

libgstreamer-plugins-base0.10-dev

libavformat-dev

libv4l-dev

libswscale-dev

Then You should configure your cmake process with this code

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BULD_TYPE=RELEASE -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=/usr/local -D BUILD_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON USE_V4L=ON WITH_TBB=ON -D BUILD_NEW_PYTHON_SUPPORT=ON USE_GStreamer=ON ..
```

Please notice USE_V4L=ON this code..

I hope you solve after reading my solution.

Answer (score 2):

```
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main()
{
  VideoCapture webcam;
  webcam.open(0);

  if(!webcam.isOpened())//**EDITED**
    {
      std::cout<<"CANNOT OPEN CAM"<<std::endl;
      return -1;
    }

  Mat frame;

  while(true)
  {
    webcam >> frame;
    imshow("TEST",frame);
    waitKey(20);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Try the above code...

Comment: if(!webcam.isOpened) line is error reporting.
../src/view.cpp:13:14: error: cannot convert ‘cv::VideoCapture::isOpened’ from type ‘bool (cv::VideoCapture::)()const’ to type ‘bool’
../src/view.cpp:13:14: error: in argument to unary !

Comment: program exiting imediately. I think, it returned -1 because !webcam is not open.

Comment: It returns CANNOT OPEN CAM

Answer (score 1):

In some cases it is down to the inbuilt cameras response time (as it was in my case). I discovered that the in-built webcam on my HP G62 only "wakes up" after the first opencv cap.read(frame) call. Therefore to get a positive read from the camera (and hence no error later in the code) I made the call several times before proceeding:

```
if (!cap.read(frame))
{
    if(!cap.read(frame))
    {
        if(!cap.read(frame))
        {
            if(!cap.read(frame))
            {
                 printf("Cam read error");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For me the optimum was 4 read calls, which ensured my camera was awake and on before running through the main block of code. It is possible that a simple "waitKey" call would work and only two read calls, although I haven't tried this.

Comment: Actually, your situation is very interesting. Do you give some extra details about your computer configuration?

Comment: You should probably use a for-loop instead of nested if's.