# OpenCV - CvVideoWriter codec error in raspbian

Tags: c, opencv, ffmpeg, webcam, gstreamer

I'm making something like black box in raspberry pi.

I set OpenCV 2.4.3 and many video libraries.
( I referred this site - [Opencv cannot acces my webcam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14424325/opencv-cannot-acces-my-webcam) )

And I compiled this sample code.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "opencv/cv.h"
#include "opencv/highgui.h"
#include "opencv/cxcore.h"

int main(void){
    CvCapture* capture = cvCaptureFromCAM(0);
    cvNameWindow("video", 1);

    double fps = cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FPS);
    CvSize frame_size = cvSize((int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH), (int)cvGetCaptureProperty(capture, CV_CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT));
    CvVideoWriter* writer = cvCreateVideoWriter("out.avi", -1, fps, frame_size, 1);

    IpImage* frame;
    while(1){
        frame = cvQueryFrame(capture);
        cvShowImage("video", frame);
        if(cvWaitKey(38) == 27){
            break;
        }
    }

    cvReleaseVideoWriter(&writer);
    cvReleaseCapture(&capture);
    cvDestroyWindow("video");

    return 0;
}
```

This code compiled successfully.

But when i run this process, there are some error.

```
OpenCV Error: Unsupported format or combination of formats (Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally.) in CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open, file /home/pi/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp, line 479
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'cv::Exception'
what(): /home/pi/OpenCV-2.4.3/modules/highgui/src/cap_gstreamer.cpp:479: error: (-210) Gstreamer Opencv backend doesn't support this codec acutally. in function CvVideoWriter_GStreamer::open

Aborted
```

So, i changed codec part in 'cvCreateVideoWriter' instead of -1.
I tried many types of codec like 'CV_FOURCC('M','J','P','G')'  and so on..

but I cannot fix this problem.

How can i solve this problem? Please help me..